# Border in layout has a unexpected space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have a layout with a border. My problem is, that between the border and the other layout's there is an space, but i don't know where it comes from.

[image: space between border and other element]

My layout looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/BackgroundLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<!-- Layout come's here :) -->
</LinearLayout>
```

The style for the BackgroundLayout looks like:

```
<style name="BackgroundLayout">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/frame_border</item>   
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/line_width</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/line_width</item>
</style>
```

and the frame_border (is a drawable.xml) looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
          <stroke
              android:width="@dimen/line_width"
              android:color="@color/background_color" />
          <solid android:color="@color/background_color" />

        </shape>
      </item>
      <item
          android:left="@dimen/line_width"
          android:right="@dimen/line_width"
          android:bottom="@dimen/line_width">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/background" android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"     />
      </item>
</layer-list>
```

the size of @dimen/line_width is 5dp.

the padding in my style has the same size as the border. so there should be any differenze (hope so).

**EDIT:**
To demostrate the issue I created a new view (see below). The background stays the same. The view (LinearLayout is the black area):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    style="@style/BackgroundLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

### Solution

My solution so far is to change the background image position from @dimen/line_width (5dp) to 5.5dp. Not satisfying, but it works.

```
  <item
      android:left="5.5dp"
      android:right="5.5dp"
      android:bottom="5.5dp">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/background" android:gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"/>
  </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Not 100% sure, but maybe it's an issue with the stock android divider.  The following code works for me.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="4dip"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@drawable/horizontal_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#fd9f8d" />
    <stroke android:width="4dip" android:color="#BDBCBC"/>
</shape>
```

horizontal_divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        android:width="2dip"
    />
    <size
        android:height="1dip"
    />
</shape>
```

[image: result after edit]

Comment: The padding should have the same size as the border (see drawable.xml)

Comment: You still shouldn't need padding on the parent element if you want the child element (which I'm assuming is your list view) to completely "match_parent"

Comment: Might be something to do with the stock android divider?  See edit.

Comment: I use a custom android divider. and i got the problem with other views as well. I edited my question and added an other example.

Comment: sry for writing so many comments. I got a solution, see my edits. Its not satisfying but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is from :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/BackgroundLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <!-- Layout come's here :) -->
 </LinearLayout>
```

Your style has padding in it. Check back and post the result.

Comment: the padding has the same size as the blue border. as so there should not be any space.